# how to properly fire Leaflet MarkerCluster clusterclick event

Tags: leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

I would like to simulate a click to a MarkerClusterGroup. I am trying to fire the `clusterclick` event on a MarkerCluster using the method below:

```javascript
clusterGroup.fire('clusterclick');
```

but I get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'zoomToBounds' of undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

First you should realize that the `"clusterclick"` event is normally triggered by clicking on an individual cluster, not on the entire group. That event calls a specific behaviour that depends on the actual clicked cluster (typically, it zooms on the bounds of the markers contained within that cluster).

Therefore you are just missing an [event data object](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#event-objects) that specifies which cluster is simulated to have been clicked on. It should be the [2nd argument of `fire()` method](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#events-fireevent).

Another possibility would be to fire a `"click"` event directly on a selected cluster. That would automatically fire the `"clusterclick"` event on the group, with the correct event data object.